What is this color difference on Composite Booms observed in the deployment of iROSA?
iROSA or ROSA deployment always amuses me. Looking at the videos that are available online, I observed something which I wasn't able to answer due the limited knowledge that I have.
As you can see in the image below which I have shown, how come during deployment the black colored region which is the composite boom is not visible in the back view as it's deploying (as you can see it's still white)?
Some thoughts that I have

Is it a cover for the composite boom? But by looking at the video it seems like the cover is also rotating along with the boom which shouldn't be the case.


I am referring to the links which might be helpful for better visualisation

Rollout Solar Array deployed during spacewalk outside space station


potentially related to color in space photography: The Dress

@uhoh Interesting find. But need more clarity on how much true it is? Have you come across something similar to this in any other video/photograph?

There are only 9 views in 3 hours so far (and it's a holiday); I think someone more knowledgable than I will be able to address this within the next day or two. In he mean time, you can check some of the references, images and/or videos foun on other pages with the roll-out-solar-array tag, for example How does ROSA unroll? (Roll Out Solar Array)

or maybe How do the roll-rings at the ISS work?

@uhoh Thankyou for the links. Appreciate it but unable to find any useful answer highlighting the problem that I have stated.
